# Why is my deployed application still reading the cshtml view instead of the precompiled view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor, precompiled-views

I am precompiling my razor views in my VS publish profile by setting the following properties:

1. Precompile options: deselect "Allow precompile site to be updatable", deselect "Emit debug information"
2. Merge options: select "Merge all outputs to a single assembly", give name "AppCode", check "Treat as library component (remove the AppCode.compiled file).

In order to test whether my application was actually reading from the compiled views, I renamed one of my cshtml files, and tested locally. All good, the view still loaded fine indicating that the compiled view was being called.

However, when I deployed all the binaries to the server and did the same test by renaming a cshtml file, the browser responsed with server 500 error.

What am I missing please?

Comment: Look in the bin folder of your published app and find the .compiled file for your cshtml file. Inside it has a reference to the View it's expecting to use.

Comment: I know there is a reference to the file within the compiled view, but that is irrelevant. The application is supposed to read the compiled view only, and not as a reference to read the actual view. Or is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue turned out to be the missing `PrecompiledApp.config` file that was not uploaded to the server. After uploading the file, all good.